# How do I implement equality compare operators for Boost.Hana Structs?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-hana

Let's say we have Boost.Hana Struct:

```c++
struct SomeStruct {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(SomeStruct, (int, x), (double, y), (char, c));
};
```

I would like to compare `SomeStruct` as `s1 == s2` and `s1 != s2`.

If I add both operators to structure definition like

```c++
struct SomeStruct {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(SomeStruct, (int, x), (double, y), (char, c));

  constexpr bool operator == (SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::equal(*this, other);
  }

  constexpr bool operator != (SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::not_equal(*this, other);
  }
};
```

code will not compile, because `SomeStruct` becomes both `Struct` and `EqualityComparable`.

Solution like

```c++
struct SomeStruct {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(SomeStruct, (int, x), (double, y), (char, c));

  constexpr bool operator == (SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::equal(boost::hana::members(*this),
                              boost::hana::members(other));
  }

  constexpr bool operator != (SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::not_equal(boost::hana::members(*this),
                                  boost::hana::members(other));
  }
};
```

will work until there are no nested Hana Structs (with the same implementation of `operator==()` and `operator!=()`) inside `SomeStruct`.

What is the correct way to define equality compare operators for Boost.Hana Structs?

UPDATE:
I need `SomeStruct` equality compare operators instead of `boost::hana::equal()` because, for example, they are needed for equality comparison of `std::optional<SomeStruct>` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. I made an issue on Boost.Hana's Github for this (https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/460)

You could specialize `boost::hana::detail::EqualityComparable` for your type to workaround this if you really wanted it to work now.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct SomeStruct {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(SomeStruct, (int, x), (int, y), (char, c));

  constexpr bool operator == (SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::equal(boost::hana::members(*this),
                              boost::hana::members(other));
  }

  constexpr bool operator != (SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::not_equal(boost::hana::members(*this),
                                  boost::hana::members(other));
  }
};

// horrible workaround
namespace boost::hana::detail {
  template <>
  struct EqualityComparable<SomeStruct> : std::false_type { };
}

int main() {
    // OK
    static_assert(SomeStruct{5, 5, 5} == SomeStruct{5, 5, 5});
    // FAIL (ambiguous template instantiation with detail::EqualityComparable
    //       without horrible workaround)
    static_assert(hana::equal(SomeStruct{5, 5, 5}, SomeStruct{5, 5, 5}));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Eu64Ng

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/4f5157bc425eac8e115d597142932fef2e535282

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap your `SomeStruct` with `SomeStructWrapper` that has as a member `SomeStruct` and in its `operator==()` and `operator!=()` calls `boost::haha::equal()`:

```
struct SomeStructWrapper
{
    SomeStruct someStruct;

    constexpr bool operator == (SomeStructWrapper const& other) 
    {
        return boost::haha::equal(this->someStruct, other.someStruct);
    }
};
```

Comment: In this case I lose all Boost.Hana Struct magic using `SomeStructWrapper`... I know that I still can use `SomeStructWrapper::someStruct` as Hana Struct but it is not so convenient

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you define binary operators as free functions?

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

struct SomeStruct {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(SomeStruct, (int, x), (double, y), (char, c));
};

constexpr bool operator == (SomeStruct const& some, SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::equal(boost::hana::members(some),
                                boost::hana::members(other));
}

constexpr bool operator != (SomeStruct const& some, SomeStruct const& other) {
    return boost::hana::not_equal(boost::hana::members(some),
                                    boost::hana::members(other));
}
```

Comment: `SomeStruct` become `Struct` and `EqualityComparable`. That will work until you have the same nested structure in `SomeStruct`, `hana::equal()` will produce compile-time errors.